# Symmetric Matrix A of Trace Zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Just wondering what that term means. I'll provide the following context to the problem:

That is, the entries of A satisfy

$a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ for all $i, j$ and $a_{11} + ... + a_{nn} = 0$

Comment: Your "context" is the definition. The matrix $A$ has entries satisfying those properties.

Comment: But what does "trace zero" mean?

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace is the sum of the diagonal elements.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1):

For instance,  $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\dots &0\\0&1&0\dots&0 \\0&0&1\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0\dots&1-n\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is symmetric

$$ A = Q \Lambda Q^{T}  \tag{1} $$

The trace is the sum of diagonal entries. In this case it is the eigenvalues.
$$ tr(A) = tr(Q \Lambda Q^{T}) = tr(\Lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} \tag{2} $$

and you have

$$ tr(\Lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} = 0 \tag{3} $$